# ssrs clear report parameters value

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report

I have one drop down report parameter named 'Category'. When value for Category is selected based on that value users from that corresponding category gets populated in second multivalue parameter called 'Users'. 
'Users' is multivalue parameter and its a very big list and Its inconvenient for user to go through that big list just to select particular user. So I have one other report parameter called 'EnterNames' where user can directly enter the names of user he already knows about. This field is optional for user.

Now the problem is:

1. When user enter value in 'EnterNames' and renders report after that when he changes the category 'EnterNames' continues to show the values entered by user which doesn't not belong in this 'Category. So here users always have to clear 'EnterNames' manually which is not a good user experience.

So is there any way to clear 'EnterNames' based on the value of 'Category'?
Or is there any way to avoid user going through that big list to select users and make it little more user friendly?

Comment: Alas, the only thing that I've found that makes SSRS clear entered values from a cascaded parameter is when a new value is added to its available value list.  Which obviously isn't an option for a type-in list.  (So even going from "A, B, C" to "A" available doesn't clear out values.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to determine in our own SSRS endeavours there is no way to make this kind of action. It would be nice if there were event handlers on parameters but there are not as of yet.

One way to improve the user experience might be to categorize the users (possibly by division, role, or first initial) and build either an entire visual hierarchy within your SQL query (using some sort of indentation character)  which includes categories and users...

```
Categories and Users
--------------------
Division A
*Sub-Div-A1
--User1
--User2
Division B
-User5
*Sub-Div-B2
--User17
```

...or add an additional parameter for categorization hierarchy that reduces the user list further:

```
Category
---------
Division A
*Sub-Div-A1   (selected)
Division B
*Sub-Div-B2

Users  (displayed)
------
User1
User2
```